# BottomNavigationView не менять размер шрифта на активном item

Tags: android

Как сделать чтобы в активном `item` не менялся размер текста? Когда переходу на другое активити размер текста в активном `item` немного увеличивается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте эти строки в ресурсы.

`design_bottom_navigation_text_size` - размер текста в неактивном элементе

`design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size` - размер текста в выбранном элементе

```
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_text_size" tools:override="true">12sp</dimen>
<dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size" tools:override="true">12sp</dimen>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.